# Merge one column in a larger SQL-Query

Tags: mysql, sql

For my query I want to use 2 tables from a MySQL-DB: tbl_A and tbl_B.
First, I would like to define the relevant subset of a primary column (col_P) through a merger of two select queries on the two tables. And then there should be a couple of subqueries which calculate some results (res_A, res_B, ...) for this relevant subset.

At the beginning I did this only for the first table:

```
SELECT col_P, res_A, res_B FROM tbl_A
   # Sub-Query 1
   left join(
      select col_P, sum(...) res_A from tbl_A
         where ...(some conditions)
         group by col_P) as tbl_1
   using(col_P)
   # Sub-Query 2
   left join(
       select col_P, sum(...) res_B from tbl_A
         where ...(some conditions)
         group by col_P) as tbl2
   using(col_P)
# Filter for relevant col_P
WHERE col_P >... and col_P < ... and more conditions here
GROUP BY col_P
ORDER BY col_P ASC
```

This query worked fine.

Now, I needed to incorporate the second table tbl_B which also has col_P whith many identical entries but also some entries which are not in tbl_A, but would be relevant for the final result table (with one result column as a col_P-subquery on tbl_B for res_C). 
Therefore, I would like to merge the relevant col_P from both tables. Stand alone, I am able to do that with:

```
SELECT col_P from tbl_A
   WHERE ... some conditions
   GROUP by col_P
UNION
   SELECT col_P from tbl_B
      GROUP by col_P
      HAVING SUM(...)!=0 and more conditions
```

How can I incorporate the relevant col_P subset into my first Query ? I tried it with a UNION at the end, but got than an error regarding different columns in the UNIONed SELECT-statements...

To summarize: I want to have a one large query where I define the relevant col_P as the combined result of two queries on two tables. Then, for the result, I want to make a couple of subqueries on table a or b, which give me each one result column.

The result table should be look like this:

```
                col_P    res_A    res_B    res_C
 query on tbl:  a & b      a        a        b
                 ...       ..       ..       ..
```

Any help would be highly appreciated...